# Manipulating state through an out-of-class function (or alternatives)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick

hope you're having a good day. I may be about to annoy you slightly with this question given how much of a newbie I am with React.

Here's the setup: I have a "projects" page for my portfolio website where I feature one project in full with the full size image and details on the side, and under that I have a listing of all other projects. As soon as one of those is clicked, the featured project should change. A pretty simple thing to most, I'm sure, but I seem to be stuck.

Here's how I currently have it set up:

1. An array called 'projects' outside of the component class to store them, one project looks like this:

```js
  {
    key: 0,
    title: "Project title",
    description:
      "Lorem ipsum",
    details: [
      "...",
      "...",
      "..."
    ].map((detail, i) => <li key={i}>{detail}</li>),
    image: ImageObject
  },
```

2. This function (which is referenced within the class' render method) also outside of the main component class which makes a div for each project

```js
function ProjectList(props) {
  const projects = props.projects;
  const projectItems = projects.map(project => (
    <div key={project.key}>
      <a href="#">
        <img src={project.image} alt={project.title} />
      </a>
    </div>
  ));

  return <div className="row">{projectItems}</div>;
}
```

and the reference in the render method goes like this:

```js
<ProjectList projects={projects} />
```

3. Now we're going within the Projects class, with one state value called 'currentProjectIndex', and a 'setProject' function:

```js
setProject = index => {
   this.setState({ currentProjectIndex: index });
 };
```

Everything works and displays correctly, and if I manually edit the state it does show the relevant project, but I'm not sure how to proceed here. I've tried adding an onClick attribute to the div and the a tags, but it seems I can't reference setState outside of the main class, which I suppose makes sense, but the ProjectList function isn't recognized in the render method if I place it inside the main class.

I realize this may be some very basic stuff but I have a feeling I might have gone about this process entirely wrongly and that I'm on the completely wrong track here. Either that or I'm just being stupid, both of which are entirely possible. Either way, I'm super thankful for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: add a button where the click event calls setProject and pass the index (that is the project.key, right?) as parameter. You also may want to add an event.preventDefault. Hope it helps. Here is the code:

```
setProject = (event, index) => {
   event.preventDefault();
   this.setState({ currentProjectIndex: index });
 };

function ProjectList(props) {
  const projects = props.projects;
  const projectItems = projects.map(project => (
    <div key={project.key}>
      <a href="#">
        <img src={project.image} alt={project.title} />
      </a>
      <button
          type='button'
          onClick={event => { this.setProject(event, project.key) }}
      >
      Select this project
      </button>
    </div>
  ));

  return <div className="row">{projectItems}</div>;
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that still gives the same error as before: "Cannot read property 'setProject' of undefined"
I assume this is because it doesn't recognize the 'this' keyword, but I have no idea how to resolve this.
Also sorry for the very late response, busy times! Appreciate the help a lot though!

Comment: Did you pass setProject as a prop to ProjectList?
<ProjectList   projects={projects}   setProject={this.setProject} />

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes! If I do what you suggested, and then within the ProjectList function call upon setProject by typing 'props.setProject' instead of 'this.setProject', it finally works! Thanks for your response after such a long time and for your help, you're a saint.

Comment: You are welcome, Jesse! And thanks for your words. Could you upvote my answer? (up arrow) Have a nice day!